# Question about a Riemannian metric

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

For all $p \in \mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$, let $\displaystyle M(p)=\frac{1}{p^{2}(p-1)^{2}}$. Then, let $g_{p} \, : \, (u,v) \, \longmapsto \, uM(p)v$.

I am not sure about the following assertions :

- Let $M=\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$. $\big( g_{p} \big)_{p \in M}$ defines a Riemannian metric on $M$. Hence, $M$ equipped with this metric is a Riemannian manifold.
- $M$ cannot be geodesically complete for this metric because, according to Hopf-Rinow theorem, $(M,\vert \cdot \vert)$ would be a complete metric space (which it is not).

I think both are true but I'd feel better if someone could validate or invalidate these assertions.

Answer (score 1):

You have modified the standard metric by a conformal factor function which is always positive so this certainly defines a Riemannian metric.

On the other hand, the metric resembles a hyperbolic metric on the y-axis near the poles of the conformal factor, so it is actually complete "near" these points.  Whether or not it is complete "at infinity" I leave to you as an exercise (hint: integrate).

Comment: Thank you for the answer but what about the Hopf-Rinow theorem ? If $M$ equipped with this metric was complete, then $M$ as a metric space would be complete as well, right?

Comment: Whether or not it is incomplete depends on whether you run off to infinity in finite time. This is consistent with Hopf-Rinow.

Comment: I have written the differential equation for geodesics and solved it. I might be mistaken but the geodesics but not all the geodesics are defined on $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore, $M$ would be incomplete.

Comment: Here you don't even need the geodesic equation. Integrate the conformal factor to show that you run off to infinity in finite time.

Comment: Sorry but I'm new to Riemannian geometry and I'm not sure to understand what you're saying. Integrating the conformal factor has to do with the length of a curve ? Correct me if I'm wrong : in $M$ with the usual metric, the first fundamental form would write $ds^{2}=dx^{2}$ and the length of a "curve" of the form $\gamma \, : \, t \, \mapsto \, x(t)$ $(a \leq t \leq b)$ would be : $L(\gamma) = \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \vert \dot{x}(t) \vert \, dt$ and with the "new" metric, we have : $ds^{2}=M(p)dx^{2}$ and $L(\gamma) = \displaystyle \int_{a}^{b} \vert \dot{x}(t) \vert \sqrt{M(x(t))} \, dt$

Comment: That looks fine. If the curve is parametrized by arclength then the curve having finite length is the same as running off to infinity in finite time.

Comment: But if the curve is parametrized by arclength, its length is $L(\gamma) = \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{M(x(s))} \, ds$ but I cannot compute this integral... I know there must be a link with the distance 

$$ d(p,q) = \inf \lbrace \gamma \, : \, [0,1] \, \rightarrow \, M, \; \gamma(0)=p, \; \gamma(1)=q \rbrace$$

but I do not see it yet.

Comment: But you don't *need* to find the arclength parameter. The length of the curve can be calculated with respect to any parameter.

Comment: Yes but if a curve, say $\gamma$ is parametrized by arclength then $\vert \dot{x}(t) \vert =1$ and $L(\gamma) = \int \frac{1}{x(t)(x(t)-1)} \, dt$.

Comment: No, "arclength" means with respect to the Riemannian metric. Here by definition time equals distance.

Comment: Ok sorry, I misunderstood "arclength". If the curve is parametrized by arclength, its length is equal to the length of the interval on which it is defined (say $t \, \mapsto \, \tilde{\gamma}$ (with $a \leq t \leq b$) is the curve parametrized by arclength) then $L(\tilde{\gamma}) = b-a$.

Comment: If that is true, I still do not see the link with the completeness. (Sorry, I hope I'm not wasting you time here)

Comment: In dimension 1 there are only two connected complete Riemannian manifolds, namely the circle and the line. If the length is finite it can't be the line. For topological reasons it can't be the circle.

Comment: Ok ! After solving the geodesic equation, all the geodesic are either defined on $\mathbb{R}$, either on intervals of the form $] a, +\infty[$. So, the length is not finite and $M$ is complete.

Comment: One more thing : I was reading the Hopf-Rinow theorem and I think it does not apply here because it is only true for *connected* Riemannian manifolds but $M=\mathbb{R} \smallsetminus \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$ is not connected.

Comment: What do you think of my last two comments ?

Comment: Hopf-Rinow is true provided there are finitely many connected components.