# Example of complete not-connected riemannian manifold

Tags: manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geodesic

Are there examples of *complete* Riemannian manifolds which are not connected ?

This question follows my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/883607/riemannian-metric-and-geodesic-completeness). The more I think about it and the less I'm convinced it exists.

Comment: $[0,1]\cup[2,3]\subset\mathbb R$ will work. More generally, the disjoint union of two copies of any compact manifold will work.

Comment: @user161825 The closed interval $[0,1]$ is a manifold with boundary. Sometimes it is implicitly understood that a manifold has no boundary unless stated otherwise. Two copies of $\mathbb R$ is a good example in the same spirit if boundaries are to be avoided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The disjoint union of two copies of $S^1$, for example, is a Riemannian manifold which is complete but not connected.